# I need to consume WCF WebService useing ksoap2 to get a PNG image

Tags: java, c#, wcf, ksoap2

I has a webservice in WCF and I need to read a normal png file. I need insert in byte[] variable.

From android I am using ksoap2 to consume that wcf and I want to get that image stored in byte[] variable.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how to start this giving me some idea to do it

Comment: You start by reading about ksoap2 and writing code. Come back here when you face issues and need help with a **particular** problem.